# Facebook Like button likes repeating on each post + on Facebook not related to the post

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like, blogger

I would like to ask your help for [my blog](http://www.fiercekrieg.com). I spent hours trying to discover why all my like buttons had the same number of likes, so finally I could change that, but it seems it's still with the same problem, when one clicks like in a post, the same like goes to the others too.

Also, there is another issue: when you click "like" in a post and it goes to Facebook, it actually doesn't appears as the post, for example the Cocorosie show, but it is like the user liked the whole blog, for example "John liked FIERCEKRIEG at Fiercekrieg"... still the link goes to the post he actually liked. I tried to change meta contents but it didn't make much effect though.

I also tried to change my Like button code, but nothing worked. Could someone help me please? Here is the code I'm using, which better fits on my layout.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>

<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Already solved it.

The problem with the repeated like buttons I don't really know how exactly... I just kept this code and used debugger on each page. Maybe it has something to do with Open Graph and Blogger, in the end.

But the redirection and how the liked post appears on Facebook is a matter of adding Open Graph on Blogger... so I followed the steps written here [link](http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2010/07/teach-your-blogger-blog-to-speak.html)[/link].

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + "&send=false&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=35"' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;'/>
```